# Compile error when I compile Alexa AVS SDK with Android.mk

Tags: android, c++, alexa-skills-kit, avs

We will develop on the Android platform, but considering the stability problem, we decided to develop in C++ language, so we use android.mk to compile avs SDK integrated into the Android system.
But when I compile,
Always find No such file or directory

Compile log：

```
we will build IDH while u make sprdidh 
Import includes file: out/target/product/xxx/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libAVSCommon_intermediates/import_includes
target thumb C++: libAVSCommon <= external/avs-device-sdk-master/AVSCommon/AVS/src/MessageRequest.cpp
In file included from external/avs-device-sdk-master/AVSCommon/AVS/src/MessageRequest.cpp:16:0:
external/avs-device-sdk-master/AVSCommon/AVS/include/AVSCommon/AVS/MessageRequest.h:20:18: fatal error: memory: No such file or directory
```

What am I missing? Where should it find the required library?

Comment: basically it means that you are using an external library and the project couldn't find it. So you should indicate in your makefile or whatever system you are using where the project could find the lib includes.